# Trying to understand the EXACT procedural flow/logic regarding GNU makefile parsing/execution

Tags: parsing, makefile, expansion

I've been reading GNU make site, but many thing seem annoyingly left out.  It's clear that there are two stages for variable expansion, but it's not clear to me what goes on with regard to expanding/combining rules.

For example, I have a rule written here for the linker that I've purposely triggered an error with...

```
$(BUILD)/$(APP_NAME): $(OBJ_LIST)
    $(FP_COMPILER) $(PARAMS) $^ $(LPARAMS) -o $(BUILD)/$(APP_NAME)

$(BUILD)/$(APP_NAME): foo

foo:
    @echo bar
```

At some stage before the linker recipe is called, 'foo' is appended to the list of prerequisites and it shows up in the input list from expanding $^.  Because foo is not an object file we get the error.

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe -Wall -g3 build/obj/main.o build/obj/phase1.o build/obj/phase2.o build/obj/phase3.o build/obj/helper/line_fetcher.o foo -lstdc++ -lm  -o build/test.exe
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find foo: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Even listing 'foo' as .phony doesn't prevent it from showing up when $^ is expanded.  If I want to have a prerequisite target that does something before the link, I have to figure out some other place to put it so that it doesn't show up when $^ is expanded.

I'm aware there's ways to extract just the "*.o" files I want for the linker (I've already figured it out).  That isn't my question.  I'm more interested in understanding the internal logic of "make" so I don't encounter other types of bugs due to things being parsed/executed in an order I didn't expect.

Comment: Can you focus the question more tightly?  The subject matter is on topic here, except for the request at the end for off-site resources, but the question is too broad.

Comment: Sorry.  I just get massively aggravated trying to learn this stuff on my own and all resources I can find leave out important details.  I am completely self-learning how to create makelines.  I should probably focus on one question at a time.  Too tired now.  I will edit tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

There are far too many very different questions here for a SO question.  Please choose one question and ask it with clarity.

You seem to have already found [the best resource](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html) for this, the GNU make manual.  You ask:

> What isn't explained is how and when rulesets themselves are expanded.

but that is explained, [in that same page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html#Rule-Definition) which shows how rules are expanded:

```
immediate : immediate ; deferred
        deferred
```

If that's not the answer you want you need to focus your question more clearly and explain what about this is not clear.

You also ask:

> If I want to have a prerequisite target that does something before the link, I have to figure out some other place to put it so that it doesn't show up when $^ is expanded.

There is no "other place to put it".  Makefiles have only targets and prerequisites, and the definition of `$^` is that it expands to *all* the prerequisites.  That's it.  There's nothing else.

If there are some prerequisites that you don't want to appear in the link line, you have to use a function to only expand to the ones you want, for example `$(filter %.o,$^)`.

Comment: No it doesn't explain what I was asking.  I am not asking when variables contained WITHIN sections of a rule are expanded.  I am asking when and how DIFFERENT rules written in different places within the makefile, yet referring to the same target are combined/resolved.  If the order was simply the order they appear in the file, I wouldn't get the error where a prerequisites written lower down in the file shows up when $^ is expanded higher up.

Comment: As for "other place to put it".  I was talking about the "phony" target foo, not the auto variable $^.

Comment: Rules are internalized as they are read in by the makefile. _I wouldn't get the error where a prerequisites written lower down in the file shows up when $^ is expanded higher up_ Yes you would, because as the manual says the `$^` expansion in the recipe is _deferred_ not immediate.  So the `$^` is not expanded until the recipe is executed, and that doesn't happen until the second phase when all the makefiles have already been parsed.  So, when `$^` is expanded all prerequisites have been added to the target, from all makefiles.

Comment: _I was talking about the "phony" target foo, not the auto variable $^_ sorry I didn't understand that.  Whether targets are phony or not, and what order they appear in the makefile, doesn't have anything to do with whether they appear in the `$^` automatic variable.  All prerequisites of a target, defined anywhere in the makefile, of any "type", are always present in `$^`.

Comment: Okay.  I think you answered my question.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but rules are combined internally such that each unique target has pointers to *all* of its prerequisites, wherever they may appear.  This internal combining phase occurs *after* the make process is finished with the initial parsing phase of the file(s), but *before* the second phase where automatic variables and 'deferred' expressions appearing inside recipes are expanded.

Comment: That's correct.  Technically, make constructs a directed acyclic graph in memory where the nodes of the graph are targets and the edges are prerequisite relationships.  As for expansion of recipes, it happens at the time where the target is deemed out of date and needs to be rebuilt, so make can run the recipe.  If a target is not considered, or is considered but is up to date, then the recipe is never expanded.

Comment: Thanks.  That completely answers my main question.  I believe the GNU make documentation implied this, but the wording went over my head for some reason.